# when I change combobox1 it also changes the values in combobox2 (both use the same List)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've 2 combobox on my winform. Both comboboxes are loaded by the list below. Everything works fine. Except, when I change a value in Combobox1 then it also changes the value in combobox2... and the same for other combobox.  When I change a value in combobox 2 it changes in combobox1....

Both have to use the same list of values. so that's the reason why I just bind to the same list (_item).

so what do I need to do to decouple the 2 comboboxes from each other?

```
   IList<CompteGeneral> _item = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);
            combobox1.DataSource = _item;
            combobox1.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";

            combobox2.DataSource = _item;
            combobox2.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the Clone method from `ICloneable` interface on `CompteGeneral`

```
  IList<CompteGeneral> _item = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);
            combobox1.DataSource = _item;
            combobox1.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";

            combobox2.DataSource = _item.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList();
            combobox2.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";
```

Also search for ShallowCopy and DeepCopy paradigms when cloning objects.

Comment: I think this is more useful in my case because I will have 15 combobox all bind to 1 list and this is less coding... just clone... thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<CompteGeneral> _item = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);
IList<CompteGeneral> _item1 = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);
combobox1.DataSource = _item;
combobox1.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";

combobox2.DataSource = _item1;
combobox2.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";
```

or

```
IList<CompteGeneral> _item = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);
BindingSource source=new BindingSource();
source.DataSource=_item ;
BindingSource source1=new BindingSource();
source1.DataSource=_item ;


combobox1.DataSource = source;
combobox1.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";

combobox2.DataSource = source1;
combobox2.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";
```

[example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/09/19/binding-multiple-comboboxes-to-the-same-datasource.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new List with the same item by passing the `_item1` in the constructor.

Assign the new list to the second Combobox.

```
        IList<CompteGeneral> _item1 = new List<CompteGeneral>(compt_repository.GetAll);

        IList<CompteGeneral> _item2 = new List<CompteGeneral>(_item1);

        combobox1.DataSource = _item1;
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";

        combobox2.DataSource = _item2;
        combobox2.DisplayMember = "AccountNumber";
```